# ¿como comparar la suma de una con cada uno de los elementos de la lista enlazada?

Tags: java

Buenas tardes como puedo comparar cada uno de los elementos de una lista enlazada con la suma de la misma ?
Ejemplo

tengo una lista con los siguientes elemento [2, 4 ,2 , -6] la suma daria como resultado 2 , ahora como hago para comparar el resultado con cada uno de los elementos y si la suma es igual a un elemento debe agregar un nuevo elemento de valor  0

resultado

asi deberia quedar la lista  -->
[2, 0 4 , 0, -6]

tengo los siguiente metodos

```
public int sumaLista(Lista s) {
        NodoLista aux = inicio;
        int suma = 0;
        while (aux != null) {
            suma += aux.getInformacion();
            aux = aux.getSiguente();
        }
        return suma;

    }

   public void comparar(Lista s) {
        NodoLista aux = inicio;
        int suma = sumaLista(s);
        Lista l = new Lista();
        while (l.getInicio() != null) {
            l.agregarNodoAlFinal(l.getInicio().getInformacion());
            if (l.getInicio().getInformacion() == suma) {
                l.agregarNodoAlFinal(0);
            }
        }
        while (l.getInicio() != null) {            
            l.agregarNodoAlFinal(l.getInicio().getInformacion());
        }
    }
```

pero no me agrega el 0 despues del 2, alguna solucion ? gracias de ante mano

Comment: @lobos tienes razon estaba iterando una lista vacia pero aun asi aun no veo el el porque no me guarda el 0, me hace falta algo ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El proceso sería parecido a recorrer la lista para sumar los valores.

```
public void comparar(Lista s) {

    NodoLista aux = s.getInicio();

    int suma = sumaLista(s);

    while (aux != null) {


        aux = aux.getSiguiente();

    }
}
```

Para agregar el nodo con valor 0 sería así:

Si el valor del nodo `aux` es igual a suma:

```
 if(aux.getInformacion() == suma){
```

Entonces crear un nuevo nodo con valor 0:

```
NodoLista nodo = new NodoLista(0);
```

Luego hacer que el nodo siguiente del nuevo `nodo` apunte al nodo siguiente del nodo `aux`:

```
nodo.setSiguiente(aux.getSiguiente());
```

Luego hacer que el nodo siguiente del nodo `aux` sea el `nodo`:

```
aux.setSiguiente(nodo);
```

El método completo quedaría así:

```
public void comparar(Lista s) {

    NodoLista aux = s.getInicio();

    int suma = sumaLista(s);

    while (aux != null) {


        if (aux.getInformacion() == suma) {

            NodoLista nodo = new NodoLista(0);

            nodo.setSiguiente(aux.getSiguiente());

            aux.setSiguiente(nodo);

        }

        aux = aux.getSiguiente();
    }
}
```